# Trying to put a table into an article in a multicols environment

Tags: tables, multicol

I have made a table outside of the multicols environment but I cant seem to format it to work inside the columns. The code for the table is below.

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
            \makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{
                \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
     \hline
     Compound & Proportion \\ [0.5ex] 
     \hline\hline
     SiO\textsubscript{2} & 67.5\% \\ 
     \hline
     Al\textsubscript{2}O\textsubscript{3} & 13.5\% \\
     \hline
     Fe\textsubscript{2}O\textsubscript{3} & 4.5\% \\
     \hline
     CO\textsubscript{2} & 4.5\% \\
     \hline
     H\textsubscript{2}O & 10\% \\ [1ex] 
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{CAPTION}
    \label{TABLE}
\end{minipage}
        }}
\end{table}
```

If anyone knows how to format this properly that would be great!

Comment: remove the makebox, parbox and  that are doing nothing and place the tabular in a minipage that is `\columnwidh` wide. `\captionof` syntax has two arguments`\captionof{table}{your caption}`

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but you may want to take a look into packages dedicated to chemical sum formulae. With `chemformula` or `mhchem`, you can replace the quite lengthy `H\textsubscript{2}O` with `\ch{H2O}`or `\ce{H2O}`.

Comment: Inside multicols column floats are not supported (as documented in the docu), only full page wide floats are, eg `table*`. If you intend to "fake" the table then just use `\captionof`but not a table environment on the outside.